# SQL INSERT Multiple records into new table from 1 record in an existing table with calculated colmns

Tags: sql, function, insert, while-loop, calculated-field

I have the following data as an example:

```
EMP NR  Date    Hours1  Hours2  Hours3  Hours4  Dep Man
1234    16/06/2014  9.5 3   0   0   13  2
1235    16/06/2014  9.5 8   2   8   12  6
1236    16/06/2014  9.5 0   0   0   11  2
```

I then need to add data into a new table that looks at the first record in the first table and for the Hours1, Hours2, Hours3 and Hours 4 column adds a new record into the new table of the Hours for each column as well as a calculated value for what column it came from. If the value of any of the Hours column is 0 then it should be ignored.

```
EMP NR  HRS Cat Hours   Dep Man
1234    1   9.5 13  2
1234    2   3   13  2
1235    1   9.5 12  6
1235    2   8   12  6
1235    3   2   12  6
1235    4   8   12  6
1236    1   9.5 11  2
```

So in some cases there are multiple entries in the 2nd table for a single entry in the first table.

If anyone knows how this can be done in SQL either with a stored procedure or even a select statement I'd greatly appreciate it.

My idea on how to do this would be to write a stored procedure that selects the existing data and with a while loop performs the calculations required and then adds the data into the new table, I'm just stuck on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

how about 4 different selects?
`SELECT EMP_NR, Hours1 INTO new_table FROM orig_table WHERE Hours1 <> 0
SELECT EMP_NR, Hours2 INTO new_table FROM orig_table WHERE Hours1 <> 0`
etc...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in a single UNION, specifying the `HRS Cat` constant in each part:

```
select "EMP NR", 1 as "HRS Cat", Hours1 as Hours, Dep, Man
from Table1
where Hours1 <> 0
union all
select "EMP NR", 2 as "HRS Cat", Hours2 as Hours, Dep, Man
from Table1
where Hours2 <> 0
union all
select "EMP NR", 3 as "HRS Cat", Hours3 as Hours, Dep, Man
from Table1
where Hours3 <> 0
union all
select "EMP NR", 4 as "HRS Cat", Hours4 as Hours, Dep, Man
from Table1
where Hours4 <> 0
```

I might be missing something though, because you mention "calculations" and there are none here.

Answer (score 0):

The below insert query would probably help you:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (EMP_NR, HRS_CAT, HOURS, DEP, MAN)
SELECT EMP_NR, 1 HRS_CAT, HOURS1 AS HOURS, DEP, MAN
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE HOURS1 <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_NR, 2 HRS_CAT, HOURS2 AS HOURS, DEP, MAN
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE HOURS2 <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_NR, 3 HRS_CAT, HOURS3 AS HOURS, DEP, MAN
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE HOURS3 <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_NR, 4 HRS_CAT, HOURS4 AS HOURS, DEP, MAN
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE HOURS4 <> 0;
```

**Syntax**

```
INSERT INTO table_name
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```